# How do I assign selected WPF datagrid row columns to variables. (VB.NET)

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I have a datagrid with customer data such as ID, name, email, phone etc.
When I select a row (with a button or selectionchanged) I want to store that row's columns in variables like

dim email as string
dim name as string
email = dgCustomers.theselectedrow.theselectedcell
name = dgCustomers.theselectedrow.theselectedcell

If I have a datatable with only one row I know I can get column data with:
dim email as string = CustomerDataTableInstance.rows(0).Item("Email")

I don't know how to get the selected row number though when I have several rows and the user clicks one/uses the keyboard.

The datagrid is bound to a datatable, not a class with object collections.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Did you try the `SelectedItem` or `SelectedIndex` properties?

I don't know much about using datatables, but I suspect you can get some kind of row object that represents a row from the datatable, by using `SelectedItem`, which you can then use to get each of the columns you want--which is just like binding to a collection of objects works.

If that doesn't work, try the `SelectedIndex` property. I'm pretty sure it exists, but I might be wrong since I never use it--I always just bind my data to SelectedItem.

Answer (score 0):

I just answered a similar question for someone else.  Please see [VB.NET WPF How to get the column value from datagrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40295126/vb-net-wpf-how-to-get-the-column-value-from-datagrid/40345892#40345892) for more detail, but Benny Jobigan is correct, you would use the SelectedIndex to get at your row, then use the Item collection to get at your column values.  It would look something similar to this:

```
    Dim View As DataView = TryCast(DataGrid1.ItemsSource, DataView)
    If View IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim ViewRow As DataRowView = View.Item(DataGrid1.SelectedIndex)
        Dim ColumnValue As Object = ViewRow.Item("ID")  ' or ViewRow.Item(0) for positional value.

        ' do something with ColumnValue here.
    End If
```

Hope that helps!